# thread class instance creating a thread function

Tags: python

I have a thread class, in it, I want to create a thread function to do its job corrurently with the thread instance. Is it possible, if yes, how ?

run function of thread class is doing a job at every, excatly, x seconds. I want to create a thread function to do a job parallel with the run function.

```
class Concurrent(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,consType, consTemp):
           # something

    def run(self):

          # make foo as a thread

    def foo (self):
          # something
```

If not, think  about below case, is it possible, how ?

```
class Concurrent(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,consType, consTemp):
           # something

    def run(self):

          # make foo as a thread

def foo ():
    # something
```

If it is unclear, please tell . I will try to reedit

Answer (score 0):

Just launch another thread. You already know how to create them and start them, so simply write another sublcass of `Thread` and `start()` it along the ones you already have.

Change `def foo()` for a `Thread` subclass with `run()` instead of `foo()`.

Comment: If you can, can you give me expilicit answer. ( english is not my native language. I do not understand well )

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest the you will reconsider using threads. In most cases in Python you should use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.. That is because Python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).
Unless you are using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) or [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)..
If I understood you correctly, just open another thread inside the thread you already opened:

```
import threading


class FooThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, consType, consTemp):
        super(FooThread, self).__init__()
        self.consType = consType
        self.consTemp = consTemp

    def run(self):
        print 'FooThread - I just started'
        # here will be the implementation of the foo function


class Concurrent(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, consType, consTemp):
        super(Concurrent, self).__init__()
        self.consType = consType
        self.consTemp = consTemp

    def run(self):
        print 'Concurrent - I just started'
        threadFoo = FooThread('consType', 'consTemp')
        threadFoo.start()
        # do something every X seconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Concurrent('consType', 'consTemp')
    thread.start()
```

The output of the program will be:

> Concurrent - I just started
> FooThread - I just started